# How to alter type of a column who is references as Foreign key in other table?

Tags: sql-server

I want to change the dataType of primary key from `varchar` to `bigint`.

I tried following command.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Company
ALTER COLUMN Id bigint
```

but it is not working as this column is referenced as the foreign key in other tables.

**How can i change its type without loosing data of the table through Sql Query?**

Comment: You have to drop the reference before altering the column then recreate the reference afterwards. Best done in a a transaction. Eventually you might need to buffer the data from that column in a temp table to recreate it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to accomplish this. But the main thing, is that first you'll have to drop the key.
First drop the primary (change name_of_primary_key, with yours real):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Company DROP CONSTRAINT name_of_primary_key;
```

Change the data type (replace `length` with your desired):

```
alter table table alter column foreign_key_column bigint(length)
```

Then drop the foreign key from other tables (make this for every table, and replace the two arguments, with your real from the db):

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_column;
```

Now, you change the data type of the foreign key column(replace `length` with your desired):

```
alter table table alter column foreign_key_column bigint(length);
```

Comment: `bigint` doesn't have a specified `length` like that.